# What does this mean? Bad usage: input 'data' is not double type

Tags: r

I'm running cls and cluster packages.
I wanted to run the basic

```
cls.attrib(mymat,vect)
```

function, but I'm getting this error.

```
Bad usage: input 'data' is not double type.
```

Its usually an an error with the type of data I supplied I believe, but I ran str and class and can't find anything out of place.

```
    > class (mymat)
    [1] "matrix"
    > str(mymat)
    int [1:20, 1:2] 74 73 72 70 69 76 77 78 77 78 ...
```

and for the vector,

```
  > class(vect)
  [1] "integer"
  > str(vect)
  int [1:20] 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Aren't these the proper params to this function? What might be the reason for this error?

Comment: It looks it is not converting the integers to double, try wrapping your inputs in `as.numeric`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work...but I have a solution for now I guess. I coerced an element into double. That turned the whole matrix into double as verified by 'is.double()'. Wonder whether this is correct or a duct tape solution..

Comment: Can you show us the data you are using? So we can reproduce the example.